# If statement for updating dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df:

```
Customer      Age     Country
A                      UK
B              24      France
D              65      US
FG             41      US
```

and a list `new_cust=['A','D', 'M']`.
I would like to use an if-else statement (or another equivalent approach) to return the following values:

- if x in `new_cust` is in `df` and `Age` is not null  then return these values;
- if x in `new_cust` is in `df` and `Age` is null then return "not scored";
- if x in `new_cust` is not in `df` then add x in df and under the column Age and country add NA.

Is there any alternative to isin that can be used for returning the above?
Expected output

```
Customer      Age     Country
A                      UK
B              24      France
D              65      US
FG             41      US
M              NA      NA
```

Comment: You can try `pd.where`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case try `merge`

```
newdf = pd.DataFrame({'Customer':new_cust})
out = df.merge(newdf,how='outer')
Out[37]: 
  Customer  Age Country
0        A   ''      UK
1        B   24  France
2        D   65      US
3       FG   41      US
4        M  NaN     NaN
```